# Only recognizing one token in antlr4 grammar

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I want my grammar to recognize the following expression `&COL[0]`. I have built the following grammar:

```
array:  
ARRAY_NAME L_RIGHT_PAR (ARRAY_DIGIT|STRING) R_RIGHT_PAR;

ARRAY_DIGIT:DIGIT+; 

ARRAY_NAME: '&''COL';

STRING  : QUOT ('\\"' | ~'"')* QUOT
    ;
L_RIGHT_PAR : '[' ;
R_RIGHT_PAR : ']' ;

fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
```

This gives the error:

> mismatched input '[1]' expecting '['

It only works if I write `&COL[ 0]` with spaces between the `[` and  `]`

Comment: what? please edit this to be clear about an actual question. I am very unclear on what you're looking for.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please "Accept" it so it might serve to help others also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the grammar a bit to make it complete enough to run.  The text `&COL[0]` lexes fine with this amended grammar.

```
grammar test1;  // different name for my test rig
test1: ARRAY_NAME L_RIGHT_PAR (ARRAY_DIGIT|STRING) R_RIGHT_PAR;
ARRAY_DIGIT:DIGIT+; 
ARRAY_NAME: '&''COL';
STRING  : QUOT ('\\"' | ~'"')* QUOT
    ;
QUOT: '"'; // assumed this
L_RIGHT_PAR : '[' ;
R_RIGHT_PAR : ']' ;
fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;  // added whitespace just so I could add \r\n
```

Here's the tokenized output:

```
[@0,0:3='&COL',<ARRAY_NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='[',<'['>,1:4]
[@2,5:5='0',<ARRAY_DIGIT>,1:5]
[@3,6:6=']',<']'>,1:6]
[@4,9:8='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

So this answers the question you asked but I'm still not sure about your definition of `STRING`.  But `&COL[0]` parses great now.